# Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c

I wonder why I am getting this error:

Implicit conversion of  'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC

```
self.versionButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AdobeClean-Light" size:self.versionButton.titleLabel.font.pointSize]; <- Implicit conversion of  'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

Looking at the header file for UIFont I see that 'fontWithName' wants a CGFloat

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [self fontWithNSFont:[NSFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]];
}
```

Looking at the header file for UIFont I see that 'pointSize' returns  a CGFloat

```
- (CGFloat)pointSize
{
    return CTFontGetSize(_font);
}
```

I'm importing UIKit which imports  "UIFont.h"

Comment: Actually, looking at that line, it's hard to see how that particular error would be provoked.  I'm guessing that Xcode is maybe highlighting the wrong line or something.

Comment: (Are there any warnings you're ignoring?)

Comment: I suspect that the issue rests elsewhere, as that line compiles and runs fine here.

Comment: Did you implement `fontWithName:size:` and `pointSize`? Are you somehow trying to mix `NSFont` (which is OS X only) and `UIFont` (which is iOS only)? Is this an OS X or iOS application?

Comment: Hmm... Considering that they have the source code for `UIFont`, this must be using a library that wraps UIKit for OSX.  Perhaps there is an import warning and Xcode is inferring a type return type of `int`.

Comment: If the UIFont class or fontWithName method were not recognized, the compiler would infer an int return code, and that could cause the error.  But the compiler should already be screaming bloody murder about the undefined stuff.

Comment: Martin, good call. Here is what was happening. We are working on an IOS application. We are using shared libraries from other projects.

Comment: One of those projects supports IOS and OSX. They had included a project that included a third party source known as chameleon.
This source allows UIKit calls to be map to AppKit calls. When I looked at what UIFont.h this specific .m file was referencing, it was the one on the  chameleon. Which does mix IOS and OSX. I removed the chameleon source as our project is IOS only and the errors went away.
 Anyway, thanks for the hint. I spent a bit of time before posing this question trying to track it down.

Comment: I also think Brian was onto it as well. :)

Comment: @user2665402: If you found the solution to your problem then you can post it as an answer, so that future readers don't have to read all comments.

Answer (score 2):

Martin and Brian good call. Here is what was happening. We are working on an IOS application. We are using shared libraries from other projects. One of those projects supports IOS and OSX. They had included a project that included a third party source known as chameleon. This source allows UIKit calls to be map to AppKit calls. When I looked at what UIFont.h this specific .m file was referencing, it was the one on the chameleon. Which does mix IOS and OSX. I removed the chameleon source as our project is IOS only and the errors went away. Anyway, thanks for the hint. I spent a bit of time before posing this question trying to track it down.